# nodemon install ang running globally by not run

Tags: node.js, nodemon

nodemon : File C:\Users\RISHABH GAUTAM\AppData\Roaming\npm\nodemon.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For
more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1

- nodemon .\index.js
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
  ```

nodemon install not work